# Firebird minimum server installation

Tags: firebird

I have installed Firebird server from the zip kit using `instsvc.exe`. The work's done well with the inno setup Exec function.

```
instsvc install -auto -name 'FireBird2_5'
```

My question is what are the minimum files necessary to install Firebird server.
The installer is too slow due to unnecessary files, I found this [link](http://www.destructor.de/firebird/minimumclient.htm) and I'm looking for something similar.

Comment: It depends on the version and features you're using. http://firebirdsql.org/en/documentation

Comment: firebird 2.5 super server with events alerter features...

Comment: So follow the link I provided, find the documentation for the version you're using, and read the minimum requirements.

Comment: What do you mean with _"what are the minimum requests to install Firebird server."_? Also, _"The installer is too slow due to unnecessary files"_ What does that even mean? Firebird's footprint is pretty small compared to other database systems. What do you want to achieve and why?

Comment: by minimum i meant's minimum files to deploys somthing like the link sited above

Comment: What do you mean by minimum, because there are some files that are technically optional, but will give you a pretty lousy experience due to missing character set support.

Comment: character set `UTF8` for the `UDFs` `rdb$set_context` & `rdb$get_context`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total size of Firebird 2.5.8 is 230 files and +/- 30MB unzipped, I doubt this would really be a problem, but if you really want to minimize things, you can remove the following.

Using [Firebird-2.5.8.27089-0_x64.zip](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/releases/download/R2_5_8/Firebird-2.5.8.27089-0_x64.zip) as the basis, you can get rid of the following files or folders because they are just examples and documentation, or files for specific purposes (if you know you need them, don't delete them):

- `doc`
- `examples`
- `help`
- `include`
- `lib`
- `misc`
- `system32`
- `udf` (most have been replaced by built-in functions anyway)
- `Readme.txt`

In theory you can remove the `intl` folder, but that will severely limit character set support in Firebird which can cause a lot of problems, so I'd advise against that.

If I'm not mistaken it should also be possible to remove `plugin\fbtrace.dll` and `fbtrace.conf`, but you may want to double check that.

From the `bin` folder, you can get rid of the following files:

- `fbguard.exe` (make sure you don't enable use of Firebird Guardian using instsvc)
- `gdef.exe` (tool for deprecated GDL DDL language)
- `gpre.exe` (preprocessor for compiling embedded SQL, unlikely you need this)
- `gsplit.exe` (tool for splitting backup files)
- `install_classic.bat`
- `install_super.bat`
- `install_superclassic.bat`
- `qli.exe` (tool for a deprecated query language)
- `uninstall.bat`

If you don't need the administrative tools (but this might not be a good idea because management, and fixing or diagnosing database problems gets harder), you can also remove from `bin`:

- `fb_lock_print.exe`
- `fbsvmgr.exe`
- `fbtracemgr.exe`
- `gbak.exe`
- `gfix.exe`
- `gsec.exe`
- `gstat.exe`
- `isql.exe`
- `nbackup.exe`

In theory you could also get rid of `fb_inet_server.exe` **or** `fbserver.exe`, depending on whether you use Classic, SuperServer or SuperClassic. Classic and SuperClassic use `fb_inet_server.exe` and SuperServer `fbserver.exe`; you can delete the other.

The other files are either technically necessary or legally necessary (the license notices).